# Sorting order behaviour between Postgres and Mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have faced some strange sort order behaviour between Postgres & mysql.

For example, i have created simple table with **varchar** column and inserted two records as below in both **Postgres and Mysql**.

```
create table mytable(name varchar(100));
insert into mytable values ('aaaa'), ('aa_a');
```

Now, i have executed simple select query with order by column.

Postgres sort order:

```
test=# select * from mytable order by (name) asc;
 name 
------
 aa_a
 aaaa
(2 rows)
```

Mysql sort order:

```
mysql> select * from mytable order by name asc;
+------+
| name |
+------+
| aaaa |
| aa_a |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Postgres and mysql both returning same records with different order.

My question is which one correct?

How to get results in same order in both database?

### Edited:

I tried with query with ORDER BY COLLATE, it solved my problem.

Tried like this

```
mysql> select * from t order by name COLLATE utf8_bin;
+------+
| name |
+------+
| aa_a |
| aaaa |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated but: don't use `(name)` in Postgres. It is actually something different than `name`. But from my understanding, MySQL's order is wrong, because the `_` should indeed come before `a` (Oracle and SQL Server sort the same way as Postgres - at least on my computer)

Comment: I will venture to guess that PostgreSQL is standards compliant and MySQL is not.

Comment: Have you tried sorting with the same (the actual keywords can be different in PostgreSQL & MySQL) *collation*? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collate.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no "correct" way to sort data.

You need to read up on "locales".

Different locales will provide (among other things) different sort orders. You might have a database using ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 which can represent several different languages. Rules for sorting English will be different for those from French or German.

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/locale.html) uses the underlying operating-system's support for locales, and not all locales are available on all platforms. The alternative is to provide your own support, but then you can have incompatibilities within one machine.

I believe [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/locale-support.html) takes the second option, but I'm no expert on MySQL.